# Cypress blur events (when input loses focus) are not triggered with headless "cypress run --browser firefox" but work with "cypress open"

Tags: javascript, firefox, automated-tests, cypress

I'm testing an Angular application with Cypress 10.4. There's a test that fails only with Firefox headless because an element that should contain a calculated sum isn't updated. Sums are calculated and updated correctly with Chrome headed/headless and Firefox headed.

The workflow that works is the following:

1. Type a number to #Expense_meter_start
2. When #Expense_meter_start loses focus (blur event) a POST request is made and the sum is updated in UI
3. Type a number to #Expense_meter_start
4. When #Expense_meter_start loses focus a POST request is made and the sum is updated in UI
5. The element containing the sum can be asserted

When I run "cypress open" and run the test with Firefox test passes. I can see the POST requests made when the elements lose focus.

**Problem: When I run "cypress run --browser firefox" the test fails each time. The sum is not what is expected.**
What I tried:
-I took screenshots and validated that the sum is indeed not updated even if the fields have values correctly.
-I created an intercept for the POST API calls. The calls are not happening with "cypress run --browser firefox". But the same calls are happening when using "cypress open".

```
    describe("Fails on headless Firefox", () => {
  it("tests blur events", () => {
    cy.visit("/");
    cy.intercept({ method: 'GET', url: '**/api/invoiceCalls/*' }).as("invoiceCalls");

    // Click to create new Invoice
    cy.contains("New invoice").click();

    // Save on dialog
    cy.get('.--primary > .button-container > .button-text').click();
    cy.wait("@invoiceCalls");

    // Type start amount
    cy.get("#Expense_meter_start").click().clear().type("200000"); // When this element loses focus aka blur event happens, POST call should happen

    // Type end amount
    cy.get("#Expense_meter_end").click().clear().type("200050"); // When this element loses focus aka blur event happens, POST call should happen

    // Type explanation of driving route
    cy.get("#Travel_expense_route").click().clear().type("Koti-Lentokenttä");

    // Check that sum is calculated
    cy.get("#Sum").should('have.text','50');

    // Click Save
    cy.get('#Save').click();

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of suggestions, Cypress has a `.blur()` command

```js
// When this element loses focus aka blur event happens, POST call should happen
cy.get("#Expense_meter_start")
  .click()
  .clear()
  .type("200000")
  .blur()              // explicitly blur this element
```

or use `{enter}`

```js
// When this element loses focus aka blur event happens, POST call should happen
cy.get("#Expense_meter_start")
  .click()
  .clear()
  .type("200000{enter}")     // blur this element with enter key
```

Comment: Explicitely calling .blur() and focus() did the trick:
cy.get("#Expense_meter_end").focus()
cy.get("#Expense_meter_end").clear().type("200050").blur();

It seems counter-productive though that if Cypress runs in the browser, we can't trust for events to always happen and have to make them happen manually.

Comment: Maybe but if a user types 2-0-0-0-0-0 and leaves the cursor there is there a POST fired? You can probably get it by `.focus()` on another element as well (which I'd expect the user would do).