# Cypress test fails in application at input field with onblur

Tags: javascript, testing, cypress

I am attempting to add Cypress tests on a legacy application, but it is always failing on an input widget which has some onblur code.

My application has:

`<input type="text" name="search" id="my_field" value="">`

and in its JS:

`$('input[id="my_field"]').onblur=trim(this.value);`

I have added a test to test the form submission, starting with typing into the field:

`cy.get('input[id="my_field"]').type('1')`

However, it fails at this point.

If I comment out the onblur javascript in the application, the test works correctly.

I've tried things like adding a .click() in the test, but it makes no difference.

I'm not sure what to try next, or why this would be failing.

Answer (score 0):

After finding [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73221024/cypress-blur-events-when-input-loses-focus-are-not-triggered-with-headless-cy#comment129330630_73227841), I found that adding .focus() fixed this.

`cy.get('input[id="my_field"]').focus().type('1')`